# Spring Security @PostFilter on Hibernate PersistenceBag causes delete

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

In general we have a client-server application using Spring Boot 2.0.2 (containing Spring Data and Spring Security) in the server.

We have a custom user object with the following implementation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @Column(name="ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   @Column(name="USERNAME", unique = true)
   private String username;

   @Column(name="PASSWORD")
   private String password;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
   @JoinTable
   (
       name="USER_INITSTATES",
       joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") },
       inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="INITSTATE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") }
   )
   private List<InitState> initStates = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<InitState> getInitStates() {
      return initStates;
   }
}
```

And we have the following implementation for retrieving the `InitState` (some kind of configuration object for the client) of the currently logged in user:

```
@PostFilter("false")
public List<InitState> loadActiveUserInitStates() {
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();

        User user = userService.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);
        return user.getInitStates(); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problematic part is where we return `user.getInitStates()`. Since the `User.initStates`-variable is configured with `FetchType.LAZY` the list is returned as a persistence bag by hibernate/jpa. Now when Spring Security evaluates the list after the retrieval via the `@PostFilter`-annotation it walks through the list and filters out the objects where no access is granted (Of course we have a more complex expression that `false` but as an example, it will do). When the filtered list is returned to the caller, hibernate wants to persist the list and deletes all `InitStates`-references from the `User`-object.

My two questions are:
* Why does Hibernate persist the list without any explicit call? Is there any documentation of this behaviour?
* (How) can I configure/disable this behaviour?

Comment: A managed entity will automatically be saved as soon as the transaction commits, that is the whole point of an managed entity. You cannot or you need to switch everything to read only. The easiest solution `return new ArrayList(user.getInitStates());`. Or write a query that obtains the `InitState` for a user. Because you use hibernate not everything has to be a (bi)directional relation.

Comment: Add @Transactional(readOnly = true) to your method .Hibernate flush persist object change and commit that by default

Comment: @M.Deinum, I solved it exactly as you suggest by wrapping it with an ArrayList. But I hoped that we could solve it with a more general, application-wide solution to prevent such "bugs" in the first place.

Comment: The general approach don't make everything a bi-directional relationship and think hard about what really makes your `User` your user...

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani I will give your solution a try.

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani your solution with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` works too. Since I find it more comprehensive than the wrapping this is my prefered solution.
@M.Deinum actually we don't have a bidirectional relation between `InitState`and `User`. The `InitState` doesn't know about the user object. Do you mean we should save the InitState ids instead of the InitStates?